# Android - try with resources just for creating database tables

Tags: android, android-sqlite

In Android I have this part of code:

```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        if(!prefs.getBoolean("firstTime", false)) {
          
            new DatabaseHelper(this);
        } }
```

Lint is now saying `'DatabaseHelper' used without 'try'-with-resources statement`

In DatabaseHelper class I have this:

```
DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);
}

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "blabla");
    }
```

So why do I need try with resources? Is it really needed here and how to do it in my case?

I tried something like:

```
try (DatabaseHelper myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this)){

} catch(IOException e) {

}
```

But I don't know what to put inside `try` statement as it is just creating the database tables and nothing else.

Strange is, if I define outside of onCreate  `DatabaseHelper myDb;` and then inside onCreate I will have:

```
myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

then it is not complaining.

Why should I assign it to myDb variable, why it is complaining when I use the same without variable as `new DatabaseHelper(this)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it really needed here...?

Yes, insofar as `SQLiteOpenHelper` [extends `AutoCloseable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/AutoCloseable), and you seem to be hitting a Lint complaint about not closing it.

> But I don't know what to put inside try statement as it is just creating the database tables and nothing else.

First, it is not creating database tables. [That will not occur until you do something with the `DatabaseHelper`, such as call `getWriteableDatabase()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper?hl=en#SQLiteOpenHelper(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory,%20int)).

Second, an `AutoCloseable` will have a `close()` method that satisfies the concern.

If your objective purely is to get rid of the Lint complaint, use:

```java
try (DatabaseHelper myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this)){
  myDb.close();
} catch(IOException e) {

}
```

You will need to do something else beyond `close()`, such as `getReadableDatabase()`, to get the tables to be created.

Comment: ah of course, I am missing there myDb.getWritableDatabase(), so in that case this can be put inside try statement. However in that case IOException is not needed according to Lint. But maybe it is better to delete this all as you suggested, and in other files where I work with data, by calling getWritableDatabase() the tables will be created in that time.

Answer (score 2):

You should put anything you want to do with `myDb` in your `try` statement
for example

```
private void executeSQL(String SQL) {

        try (DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context)) {

            SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            database.beginTransaction();
            database.execSQL(SQL);
            database.setTransactionSuccessful();
            database.endTransaction();
        }
}
```

this was the old way of doing it:

```
private void executeSQL(String SQL) {

        DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);

        SQLiteDatabase database = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        database.beginTransaction();

        try {

            database.execSQL(SQL);
            database.setTransactionSuccessful();

        } finally {

            database.endTransaction();
            database.close();
        }
    }
```

basically when you use the **try-with-resources** statement you don't need to close the database object. it will be automatically closed after the code inside the try is executed.

> The try-with-resources statement is a try statement that declares one
> or more resources. A resource is an object that must be closed after
> the program is finished with it. The try-with-resources statement
> ensures that each resource is closed at the end of the statement. Any
> object that implements java.lang.AutoCloseable, which includes all
> objects which implement java.io.Closeable, can be used as a resource.

more on that here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html